# Domain Content at Different URL

Tags: domains, web-hosting

I know next to nothing pertaining to this topic, so I will do my best to describe my situation. I tried looking for answers, but I think I just need someone to put it into layman's terms for me.

I am working with a client who is planning to make a subdomain on their parent company's site. Let's call it "foundation.example.com". Example.com will create the subdomain, but is not allowing the client to host any files on their server.

The solution proposed would be to purchase hosting elsewhere, but have the site point to foundation.example.com. The goal is to make it seem as if the user is on foundation.example.com, since that is what will show up in the address bar.

How can I achieve this? All responses appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You don't actually ask a question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subdomains can point to different servers. `example.com` is irrelevant to the user in this scenario since the user really will be at `foundation.example.com` and seeing files hosted at `foundation.example.com`. The DNS server points the user to the correct location, `example.com` doesn't point the user there. `example.com`'s only role is to control access to subdomains at the DNS provider.

Example:

- Domain 1: `example.com` resides at IP address `10.0.0.1`
- Domain 2: `foundation.example.com` resides at IP address `10.0.0.2`

Please clarify your question at: "The goal is to make it seem as if the user is on `foundation.example.com`, since that is what will show up in the address bar.", Since the user really is at `foundation.example.com` server, I don't understand what you are saying there.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Perhaps I should have clarified...

Example.com is using a vendor with their own CMS service to host the site, so using a subdomain on their server that doesn't utilize their services isn't going to possible. This has lead us to try to host elsewhere, but point the domain towards example.com.

We would like a user to type in "foundation.example.com" into their browser and see the content from the new domain we plan to purchase, but still have it say "foundation.example.com" as their url. Hope that helps.

Comment: That is possible. Example.com will have to create a record at their DNS provider that points foundation.example.com subdomain to your new server. When the user types foundation.example.com it will show the content from your new server once they configure it. This is a common practice.

Comment: Much appreciated, JMC. I will go ahead with this plan. Thanks for your efforts.